# Default values for complex argument in constructor

Tags: typescript

I'm recently sorry if this question is a duplicate. However I didn't find solution for my problem. And thanks in advance for your replies.

So if I have the following interface with some optional parameters for argument in constructor

```
interface User {
    firstname: string,
    lastname: string,
    onFirstNameChanged?: (name: string) => void,
    onLastNameChanged?: (name: string) => void,
}
```

and I want to create a new instance of class where I want to provide an argument with this interface, how can I set default values for optional parameters `onFirstNameChanged` and `onLastNameChanged`?

I've tried the following code but it doesn't works and sends an exception that tells that default value wasn't set

```
 constructor(
    private user: User = {...user, onFirstNameChanged: () => {}, onLastNameChanged: () => {}}
 ) {
   // ...do some stuff
 }
```

Of course there are a lot of solutions to solve it with different ways, for example check for existing of parameters inside costructor's body but I'm asking about default values.

Example [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKoGdrIN4ChkHIzBTpghwC2EAXMmVKAOYA0%20hANnGRdXQ8zaFkAexAAxEmQByVCAGEAFnBBMIAEwD8dABS9a9MI1UBKZAF4AfMgBuI4OqGExAGW5hZ1JSrVbd%20-iNmMytbe0dcAF9cXAQudHRkABUIMhwYgEgEMQYAVwQwESgdAAdGGzhIZFzMKDoMLHMcADpWmugWUQkpDzlvVQ1dEOtsSMizPAIMgHpp5Fbm5HURehFqdmiCdgRlAc8UJp1h9KnskDT9C2QAcgAROBsIa4BudgIwRWB0ZvaoZrFJKRel5dr49HITK8CNForEcmBqrV6rUrngMsQgQEbgApESKEDXJzxchyOh3ERPKKvOHnBGQNJNEAQADuyVSYB0v0hNPQIg4EGaHBETB09LAJlwYuaOx8EH2R1eQA).

Comment: By default value, you mean setting a string or a function?

Comment: @tsecheukfung01 nevermind. in my case it's a function but I think that the problem is in another case: how to bind default value to an optional complex argument inside constructor

Comment: I think ```nameChanged``` functions should exist for every User as the ```setter``` functions. If so, you can just set the value in the constructor normally.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a checking before invoking the function

```
changeName = () => {
    const name = 'Dave';
    this.user.onFirstNameChanged && this.user.onFirstNameChanged(name)
  }
```

Or if you are sure certain function is available, use the `!` operator

```
changeName = () => {
    const name = 'Dave';
    this.user.onFirstNameChanged!(name)
}
```

I recommend the first one as that's the reason why you make those function optional using `?` operator.

Comment: Thanks a lot for reply. Obviously that there are a lot of solutions to solve problem but I'm very interesting is there a way to bind default value